# CORS support for Jax-rs 2 AsyncResponse?

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, jax-rs, glassfish-2.x

I created a rest webservice using Jax-rs 2. It uses the AsyncResponse to return the response. How I can add CORS support to my rest web services ? So any one can access it with out any cross domain issues ?

My sample rest webservice is as follows

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public void test(@Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse){
        asyncResponse.resume(Response.ok().build());
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

RestEasy has the [`CorsFilter`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But since you are using Glassfish, you are most likely using Jersey. Jersey doesn't seem to have any such class we can use. That said, the `CorsFilter` for RestEasy implements [`ContainterRequestFilter`](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) and [`ContainerResponseFilter`](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html) (Note, this is a Jersey 2.x (JAX-RS 2.0) feature).

- [See Filters and Interceptors for more information](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html)

You can also see the source code for the `CorsFilter` [here at GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/3.0.8.Final/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/interceptors/CorsFilter.java#CorsFilter). You'll basically want to implements something similar to that class, then register it is as a singleton with the application.